# Reorganise an array that has missing key items - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that outputs like this, you'll notice that in output the key for [2] has no data. How could I loop through this array and ensure the array has no missing keys and the data is sorted. With just using the data in the array.

```
print_r($layout_array); 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => home
            [row_text_title] => home
            [original_row_position] => 1
            [row_position] => 1
            [row_show] => yes
            [row_link_ref] => https://demo.ul
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => benefits
            [row_text_title] => benefits
            [row_link_ref] => #benefits
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
            [row_position] => 2
            [original_row_position] => 2
            [row_show] => yes
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => about
            [row_text_title] => about
            [row_link_ref] => #about
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
            [row_show] => no
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => team
            [row_text_title] => team
            [row_link_ref] => #team
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
            [row_position] => 4
            [original_row_position] => 4
            [row_show] => yes
        )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted"? Do you mean that you simply want to turn the array into an indexed array or are you asking for sorting on some specific value?

Comment: You can ensure you have no missing keys (0 indexed) by testing if `range(0,count($data)-1)` is the same or different to `array_keys($data)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/function.array-values.php) which basically would "reset" the keys:

`$layout_array = array_values($layout_array);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the data and reindex to remove missing keys, you can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). For example, if you want to sort by `row_identifier`:

```
$sort_by_column = 'row_identifier';
array_multisort(array_column($layout_array, $sort_by_column), $layout_array);
print_r($layout_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => about
            [row_text_title] => about
            [row_link_ref] => #about
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
            [row_show] => no
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => benefits
            [row_text_title] => benefits
            [row_link_ref] => #benefits
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
            [row_position] => 2
            [original_row_position] => 2
            [row_show] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => home
            [row_text_title] => home
            [original_row_position] => 1
            [row_position] => 1
            [row_show] => yes
            [row_link_ref] => https://demo.ul
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [row_identifier] => team
            [row_text_title] => team
            [row_link_ref] => #team
            [button_styling] => off
            [tab] => self
            [row_position] => 4
            [original_row_position] => 4
            [row_show] => yes
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nZfWS)

Note that you can only sort on a key that is present in all values. If a key is not present in all values, you will get a

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Array sizes are inconsistent

in PHP8+ or a

> Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

in PHP5.5 onwards (which you need for `array_column`), and the array will *not* be sorted.

Comment: Thanks @Nick - If I sorted on an item that didn't have a value, would it put that array item to the top or bottom

Comment: @DIM3NSION array_multisort won't work in those cases (the arrays must have the same length) so the whole array would remain unsorted

Comment: In addition to the array remaining unsorted, you'll also have an exception thrown:
`ErrorException: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent`.

Comment: @BrianHannay that's new behaviour as of PHP8; previously it just raised a warning. I'll make a note in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute without php function :

```
$new_array = array();            
foreach($test as $variable){    // $test is your array
  array_push($new_array,$variable);
}
```